# Centering google recaptcha

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I started using google captcha for a series of form submission in my site, I had to resize said captchas due to the fact that they where way to big for the modals and part of them where laying outside the modal so i resized them following the instructions [here](https://geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/). Gladly the resize worked, the captchas now appear in the correct size for the modal but they do not appear centered, and I ran out of options to center them, i tried almost everything but they refuse to be centered.

I tried adding the classes `my-auto`, `text-align: center;` and `display: inline-block;` on the captcha and `text-center` and `justify-content-center` in it's parent div's, none worked.

I get no error messages and im out of ideas too.

I am using Bootstrap 4.

Below my Modal code:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-consulta" data-backdrop="static" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">CONSULTA</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action=".\php\consulta.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Nombre</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Telefono</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Mail</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Mail" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin: 0px 0px 4px 0px;">
                        <label class="col col-form-label font-weight-bold" style="padding-left: 0px;">Consulta</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                        <textarea id="consulta" name="consulta" class="col form-control" rows="4" style="margin: 0px 15px 0px 15px;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 9px;">
                            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR CONSULTA</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">DESCARTAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below my resizing CSS code:

```css
.g-recaptcha {
    transform:scale(0.77);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.77);
    transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0;
}
```

Here's a picture:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time and I am looking forward to be part of this community of which i have heard so much positive things.

Comment: I am testing your code in desktop. It is working fine with centered.

Comment: Hm, what browser did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the left and right margin to `auto` for the button? The captcha should be put under it own `div`.
Or, use `text-align:center;` with the parent div. Remember to use an up-to-date browser too.

Answer (score 1):

Like HDP, I've tested it on desktop and it worked fine. I have used Angular to replicate it and so I've used a `<re-captcha>` tag instead of `class="g-recaptcha"`.

With which technology/frameworks did you implement the app? What browser are you using on that Android?

Looking through various old Android projects of mine, I found something you can try out. It was realised with Angular 6 and Bootstrap 4 to work on mobile devices, maybe it will help you to develop a solution:

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- Headline -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col text-center">
        <br>
        <p>
          Things are only impossible until they are not!<br>
          <br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Image/Frame -->
    <div class="row mt-2">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="frame d-flex align-content-center flex-wrap">
          <div class="mx-auto">
              <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <div class="col d-flex justify-content-center mb-5">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-checkStyle rounded-pill px-5" [disabled]="clicked" (click)="doSomething()">Register now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the `margin` and `max-width` CSS properties of `div.g-recaptcha` like in this example :

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" style="margin:auto; max-width:305px;"></div>
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, i forgive to mention the div of re-captcha. Thanks Ethan